# Chart.js horizontal bar size

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a page showing multiple horizontal bar graphs using Chart.js.

As you can see in the picture below, this looks weird because the graphs are all the same height (I'm only setting the width and maintainAspectRatio = false) and so the size of the bars are all different

[image]

Is there a way to make all bars the same size?

I tried barThickness but that just distributes the values the bars in the available space.

What I wanted was for the bars to be all the same size and graphs with more bars should grow vertically.